# Android - pass array (of object my class) to another activitie

Tags: android, arrays, android-activity

I have problem with passing array to another activity.

This is my class:

```
public class network 
{
  //something
}
```

This is Activity A:

```
network[] nets= new network[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) nets[i] = new network();
```

And I want to use array `nets` in activity B. 
How can I pass it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your class Serialzieable.
If you want to make your class Serializable you only have to implement the Serializable interface in your network class.

```
public class network implements Serializable
{
  //something
}
```

Then you can make you array to an arraylist and pass the arraylist to you intent before starting activity B:

```
Intent intentActivityB = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
ArrayList<network> netlist = new ArrayList<network>(Arrays.asList(nets));
intentActivityB.putExtra("nets", netlist);
startActivity(intentActivityB);
```

In Your activity B you can now get the ArrayList in your onCreate method:

```
List<network> networkList = 
          (ArrayList<network>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("nets");
```